# Domain not working on create-react-app nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, create-react-app

I am hosting my website in a cloud ubuntu 16.04-64, it is being displayed in 200.98.201.143. However, the mb-mock.com domain that I also setup isn't working.

Here is my default file:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  root /home/mbpower/build;
  server_name mb-mock.com 200.98.201.143;
  index index.html index.htm;
  location / {
  }
}
```

I don't know if this helps but here is the repo: https://github.com/dev-campos/mbpower

I have tried several different ways to get this website hosted and this is the farthest I got, this is the last step I haven't been able to get to work, so I'm afraid to try messing around too much and breaking the rest.

Comment: You have to point the domain to this IP through `DNS` or `A records` in your domain registrar dashboard. check [here](https://www.name.com/support/articles/205188538-Pointing-your-domain-to-hosting-with-A-records) or [here](https://godaddy.com/help/change-nameservers-for-my-domains-664) for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As awran5 said I just needed to change the domain to the correct IP.